# Could not find artifact com.sun:jconsole:jar:1.8 at specified path /home/runner/.m2/repository/com/alibaba/druid/1.2.6/lib/openjdk-1.8-jconsole.jar

Tags: java, maven

Could not find artifact com.sun:jconsole:jar:1.8 at specified path /home/runner/.m2/repository/com/alibaba/druid/1.2.6/lib/openjdk-1.8-jconsole.jar

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>druid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jconsole</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This question has no context, no details, no information about what you would like to achieve. You need to either edit this question or I have a gut feeling it's going to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jconsole</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```

Comment: Got same issue. The answer is the same as https://github.com/alibaba/druid/issues/4309#issuecomment-925514365. It works pretty well.